# Spring Boot 2.7.7 mockMvc Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: mockmvc

I have a spring boot micro service defined, all http endpoints behaving as expected. Currently testing with mock mvc.
Error in the mockMvc test:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.james.musician.model.Musician.getId()" because "savedMusician" is null

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.james.musician.model.Musician.getId()" because "savedMusician" is null
at com.james.musician.controller.MusicianController.addMusician(MusicianController.java:68)

I have an entity called Musician. Controller called musicianController, service called musicianService. The test is to verify adding a new musician. The POST call comes to the controller which calls the service layer then the service layer calls repository to save the new musician.
Here the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MusicianControllerMockMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    MusicianController musicianController;
    
    @MockBean
    MusicianRepository musicianRepo;
    
    @MockBean
    MusicianService musicianService;
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired 
    MusicianBuilder musicianBuilder;
    
    @Autowired
    ErrorValidation errorValidation;
    
    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<Musician> captor;

    @Test
    public void addMusicianControllerTest() throws Exception{
        Musician musician = musicianBuilder.buildMusician(); 
        Musician savedMusician = musicianBuilder.buildMusician();
        savedMusician.setId(1L); 
        ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = map.writeValueAsString(savedMusician);
        when(musicianService.createMusician(musician)).thenReturn(savedMusician);
        when(musicianRepo.save(musician)).thenReturn(savedMusician);
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/musicians").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(jsonString)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1L))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.msg").value("Musician Added Successfully")); 
        verify(musicianRepo, new Times(1)).save(captor.capture());
        Musician finalMusician = captor.getValue();
        assertEquals(finalMusician.getEmailAddress(),savedMusician.getEmailAddress());
        
         
    }
}
```

Controller POST method:

```
@PostMapping      
    public ResponseEntity addMusician(@RequestBody Musician musician) {
    
        AddResponse ad = new AddResponse();
    
        try {
            Musician savedMusician = musicianService.createMusician(musician);
            String longIdToString = savedMusician.getId().toString();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("unique", longIdToString);
            ad.setMsg("Musician Added Successfully"); 
            ad.setId(longIdToString);
            return new ResponseEntity<AddResponse>(ad, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            
        } catch (MusicianException e) {
            ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

musicianService:

```
@Service
public class MusicianService {
    Musician musician;
    
    @Autowired
    MusicianRepository musicianRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    ErrorValidation errorValidation;
    


    **public Musician createMusician(Musician musician) throws MusicianValidationException{
        this.musician = musician;
        
        // use email address to check if musician already exists 
        if(musicianRepo.findByEmailAddress(musician.getEmailAddress()) != null) {
            throw new MusicianValidationException(ErrorMessages.MUSISIAN_ALREADY_EXISTS.getMsg());
        }
        
        if(musician.getStyle().equals(MusicStyle.FOLK)) {
            if(!errorValidation.checkValidFolkMusician(musician)) {
                throw new MusicianValidationException(ErrorMessages.INVALID_FOLK_MUSICIAN.getMsg());
            }
        }
        if(errorValidation.checkDuplicateInstrument(musician)) {
            throw new MusicianValidationException(ErrorMessages.DUPLICATE_INSTRUMENTS.getMsg()
                    + " (" + musician.getInstrumentA() + ")");
        }
        if(!errorValidation.checkInstrumentComboAllowed(musician)) {
            throw new MusicianValidationException(ErrorMessages.INVALID_INSTRUMENT_COMBO.getMsg()
                + " (" + musician.getInstrumentA() + ", " + musician.getInstrumentB() + ")" );
        }
        return musicianRepo.save(musician); 
    } **
     


    
}
```

I'm sure the issue is that I'm not correctly mocking the behavour of the musicianService but I can't figure out what I'm missing.
The musicianController calls Musician savedMusician = musicianService.createMusician(musician);
which I've mocked in the test with:
when(musicianService.createMusician(musician)).thenReturn(savedMusician);

The issue is in the next line of the musicanController:
String longIdToString = savedMusician.getId().toString();

which gives the nullPointer:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.james.musician.model.Musician.getId()" because "savedMusician" is null

pretty new to spring boot and microservices. Any thoughts?
Apologies for any formatting issues in the question or lack of required code. First post on stackoverflow in many years.
I find a similar issue [MockMvc returns null instead of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832097/mockmvc-returns-null-instead-of-object)
but couldn't get the answer.

edit**

I've commented out the method call which is giving the null pointer:

```
String longIdToString = savedMusician.getId().toString();
```

now I see a different error from the test:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
```

`musicianRepository bean.save( <Capturing argument> );`

-> at com.james.musician.controller.MusicianControllerMockMvcTest.addMusicianControllerTest(MusicianControllerMockMvcTest.java:93)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

So the musicianRepo(save) mock appears to be incorrect:

`when(musicianRepo.save(musician)).thenReturn(savedMusician);`

regards,
James

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was trying to mock a repository save that is made from the service layer itself rather than the controller.
The test mocks the service behaviour in the controller only. The call to the repository is never made in the test from the controller class, only the call to the service layer is, and so it can't be mocked.
When I changed the verify to:

```
verify(musicianService, new Times(1)).createMusician(captor.capture());
    Musician finalMusician = captor.getValue();
    assertEquals(finalMusician.getEmailAddress(),savedMusician.getEmailAddress());
```

this test then passes.I'm not sure this is exactly what I'm trying to prove with the test but I think the logic on why the initial test fails seems solid.